# DPI Settings on Windows 2008 Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, display-settings, dpi

Is my assumption correct that changing the DPI setting on a Windows 2008 will affect all users? (The setting is per machine).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the DPI setting will affects the entire user interface including the logon interface UI and also please refer the below URL.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2544872